# How to send e-mail with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

Friends, I created a message form, but somehow I could not make the PHP code for sending e-mails. Can you help me? My codes are as below.

I keep getting the message Your email was not sent.

```
<form action="eposta.php" method="post">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="email"  name="eposta" required placeholder="E-Postanız"  value="" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="isim" placeholder="Adınız"  value="" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td></td>
      <td><textarea name="mesaj" required cols="48" rows="5" placeholder="Mesajınız..." value="" size="50"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Gönder" /></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST["eposta"]))
{

$kime = "test@hotmail.com";

$message = $_POST["mesaj"];

$baslik = "From: ".$_POST["isim"]."<".$_POST["eposta"].">\r\n";
$baslik .= "Content-type: text/php\r\n";


if (mail($kime, $message, $baslik))
    echo "E-Postanız Gönderildi.";
else
    echo "E-Postanız gönderilmedi.";

}


?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.

Comment: Your arguments are out of place. Carefully read the manual for [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: I'm checking. My goal is to receive an e-mail when the send button is pressed.

Comment: As @KIKOSoftware said, review the docs. For example, second parameter should be `subject`. Where is your subject?

Comment: @jonathan Is it necessary to add a subject?

Comment: You're attempting to use the `mail` function, but you haven't told us about the server on which you're running this code. Do you have sendmail installed? Have you followed all of the prerequisites outlined in the [PHP Mail Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)? You also aren't attempting to debug WHY your mail send is failing. Use [this snippet](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#121163) to get an actual error message so you can further debug any connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$send = mail($kime, $message, $baslik);
if (!$send) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
    print_r($errorMessage);
    echo "E-Postanız gönderilmedi.";
} else {
    echo "E-Postanız Gönderildi.";
}
```

instead of

```
if (mail($kime, $message, $baslik))
    echo "E-Postanız Gönderildi.";
else
    echo "E-Postanız gönderilmedi.";

}
```

Comment out(`//`) or remove these lines when fixed:

```
$errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
print_r($errorMessage);
```

Comment: Your subject is missing also!

Comment: Is it necessary to add a subject?

Comment: @Massaka Yes, it is. Read mail() function's documentation! https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php